# How can I create a multiple BIT column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a empty table that I want to contain rows of words. It's a simple table looking something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Words] (
    [WordId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Word]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL
    [Source] ??
);
```

What I would like to do is to populate this table from three sources. Some of the words come from source `A`, some from source `B` and some from source `C`. Most of the words come from at least two sources so there are usually at least two source for the same word.

The words from source A are stored here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordsA] (
    [WordId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Word]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

The words from source B are stored here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordsA] (
    [WordId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Word]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

The words from source C are stored here:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[WordsA] (
    [WordId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Word]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

Here's what I would like to achieve. where the Source column uses bits to indicate with a 0 or 1 where the word came from:

```
001 = Source A only
011 = Source B and source A
101 = Source C and source A

WordId    Word     Source
1         Cat      001
2         Dog      011
3         Man      101
```

What I would like to do is to have a `Source` column in the Words table that would show in BIT form where the words came from. In this example I'm showing just 3 sources but I would like to be able to have up to 12 different sources.  For this I am not sure what column datatype I should use as later on I would like to be able to do a query to for example find all words from Source B or from Source C .

Also how could I insert/update data from the source columns, into the Words table and at the same time set the `Source` column? For this I assume I would have to do an insert but if it failed then an update.

Can anyone suggest how I could do this? How can I go through each row of WordsA, WordsB and WordsC one by one inserting or updating and setting the `Source` column where appropriate?

Comment: 8 bits = 1 byte = tinyint. You can use tinyint to store 8 sources, furthermore you can use binary operators like `&` and `|` to compare those values to other values. What if you have more than 8 sources? check the numeric data types page in the doc and be creative.

Comment: Sounds like you might be trying to implement something like [SQL Server Full-Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) or a [Lucene Index](https://lucene.apache.org/core/). I don't know if a pre-packaged indexing solution to this kind of problem might be a productive route for you?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a many to many relation, and can be modelled by usage of so called bridge table

For example, you may have a table for sources, table for words and bridge table called sourcesToWords. The bridge table will contain two columns, one for example called sourceId and the second wordId. The combination of wordID and sourceID will give you all combination of word and source. And it will work with more than 12 sources. Please look up many to many relation modelling.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bunch of bit fields for your source flags and then use a calculated field to create your source column.  For example,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Words] (
    [WordId] INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Word]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [SourceA] BIT DEFAULT 0,
    [SourceB] BIT DEFAULT 0,
    [SourceC] BIT DEFAULT 0,
    [AllSources] AS CONVERT(CHAR(1), SourceC) + CONVERT(CHAR(1), SourceB) + CONVERT(CHAR(1), SourceA) 
);
```

And here are a few example insert statements to check it out:

```
INSERT Words (Word, SourceA) VALUES ('one', 1)
INSERT Words (Word, SourceB) VALUES ('word', 1)
INSERT Words (Word, SourceC) VALUES ('after', 1)
INSERT Words (Word, SourceB, SourceC) VALUES ('another', 1, 1)
```

In order to update from your source tables, you'd do updates similar to this:

```
UPDATE Words
   SET SourceA = 1
  FROM Words 
  JOIN WordsA
    ON Words.Word = WordsA.Word
```

Comment: The thing I worry about with this is it could get out of control when I start to need 12 sources.  Would there be a way I could create one column as INT and do the same thing?

Comment: You can use a `bitwise and` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174965.aspx).  I think that embedding multiple pieces of information into one column (a whole bunch of flags inside of one integer) makes the database harder to understand during maintenance.